# Is there a way to measure the weight of Javascript in a page?

Tags: javascript, performance, testing

I mean, a sort of statistic about memory taken by the browser with javascript, or any sort of testing, reaction by handlers, and so on.

Just to know how the page could be if I test it in an old computer.

Any ideas?

Comment: Print it and use a scale to measure the weight of the paper. I'm sorry, what do you mean by weight? File size, execution time, etc?

Comment: weight as general word. I said : memory taken into browser, handlers time reaction (execution), and so on! Funny your first answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebKit got a build in profiler, hit F12 when you are on windows and you will see it.

[image]

The add on FireBug for firefox can do the same, not as good but here is it:

[image]

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I use Firebug, but it says nothings about Javascript performance.

Comment: I added a screenshot from firebug, does it do what you want?

Comment: Yeah nice! But how can I says "it is good" or "it is bad"? :) Ok, I see ms, but I should know a bit of measuring, right? :)

Comment: That is a little hard to say, if one function takes up a lot of the time and makes a lot of calls, it can be bad. But it might just need to do that. I see that this picture is in Danish, it might make more sense if you try it your self, make a simple page and test it there.

Comment: If you want to see the memory being used, in Chrome of Safari, check out the `Take Heap Snapshot` feature.